# Magento category page is blank How can i see the error message

Tags: magento

My category pages `http://magento-36664-riki.vpsapps.net/ceiling-lights.html?___store=default` are blank.Even When i try to search any product i get blank page.
So I think whole catalog is not working.

I also try to change the layout of category from back office but same result

Is there any way to see the error ?

I checked server error.log file and find this message "Directory index forbidden by Options directive"

Now I again checked my server error log. Now I am getting this error"Now I am getting this error in server error log"PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 241172481 bytes) in /var/www/kkemerce/htdocs/app/Mage.php on line 842 [Fri May 03 06:26:44 2013] [error] PHP Fatal error: Class 'Mage' not found in /var/www/kkemerce/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 0"

Comment: the product are in out of stock...check it

Comment: No whole catalog was working fine.I made same change in footer and it stopped working

Answer (score 2):

I think you got blank page due to PHP errors. To make Magento show errors, you should enable developer mode by editing `index.php` like bellow:

```
....
#if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
#}

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
....
```

Comment: I tired this but did not get any error message.Now I am getting this message for category pages only "Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://magento-36664-riki.vpsapps.net/wall-lights.html?___store=default. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request."

Answer (score 2):

Regarding server error "PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes ..." in my experience this happens if:

- I try to browse product which is not inside ANY category
- I try to browse category which have attribute "is active" set to NO

It will eat ANY memory [ini_set('memory_limit','2024M') still not enough]

Perhaps this helps?

Answer (score 0):

`Directory index forbidden by Options directive` means that your virtual host settings are incorrect. Check that mod_rewrite is enabled, also check that the default .htaccess is there. Lastly, check your vhost settings & see if it has the mod_rewrite settings:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/vhosts.html

Comment: Now I am getting this error in server error log"PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 241172481 bytes) in /var/www/kkemerce/htdocs/app/Mage.php on line 842
[Fri May 03 06:26:44 2013] [error] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mage' not found in /var/www/kkemerce/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 0"

Comment: Increase memory limit by edit .htaccess like this: `php_value memory_limit 512M`. By default, Magento set limit to `php_value memory_limit 256M`. NOTE: due to server configuration, change .htaccess does not take effect, in this case, you must change in php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

you can check log goto var->log directory then you can get exception and system log file otherwise you can goto magento admin panel Sysem->configuration and find Advance tab then select devloper and select debug-> profiler select "yes"

Comment: I tired this but did not get any error message.Now I am getting this message for category pages only "Server error The website encountered an error while retrieving magento-36664-riki.vpsapps.net/…. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly. Here are some suggestions: Reload this webpage later. HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request."

Comment: It seems that your apache is configured wrong ..... and not the php code.

Hint: Take a look in the apache error log file to get more informations

Comment: write your code in try{ }catch(Exception $e){ $e->getMessage();}

Answer (score 0):

One attribute was missing while loading the catalog in grid view I put that attribute and problem get sloved

Comment: Could  you give more information for people that might get the same problem or that question on SO would a been for nothing because it doesn't help anyone

Answer (score 0):

For me disabling cache worked, seems it was cache issue.